# MFC OnTimer() method not working

Tags: mfc, timer

I created an MFC dialog based app and wanted to add timer on the form. But it turns out that MFC is different than the .NET windows forms.

I added the ON_WM_TIMER() in the messagemap.  and added the function definition for CMyDialog::OnTimer(UINT_PTR x)
{
}

But I am getting a compiler error in VS2005. I do not know what i am doing wrong. 
"error C2509: 'OnTimer' : member function not declared in 'CMyDialog'"

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the method declaration in the .h file (MyDialog.h): afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent);???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, you forgot to declare the function in `MyDialog.h`, in `CMyDialog` declaration:

```
afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT_PTR x);
```

Note that afx_msg is purely informative and can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [ON_WM_TIMER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfk31946.aspx) map macro shows that you're doing the right thing. The only thing I can think of is that you have left the `afx_msg` qualifier off of your function definition.

**Edit:** At the risk of stating the obvious, did you also include the prototype of the OnTimer function in your class declaration?